# While loop within a while loop logically not working in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I have this while loop within another while loop in my PHP:

```
$selecty = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");

$rowsy = mysql_num_rows($selecty);

echo '<td>'. $table["username"]. '</td>';
echo '<td>';

while ($tables = mysql_fetch_assoc($selecty)) {
    if($tables['followerid']!=$table['id']) {
        echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="follow">'.'</a>'; 
    } else {
        echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="following">'.'</a>';
    }
}
echo '</td>';
echo "<tr>";
```

This is more of a logic question and whether or not a nested while loop is the right way to do it. What I'm trying to say is if the 'followerid' from 'user followers table' is not the same as the 'id' from users table (which is from the previous loop) - echo the follow button, else echo the following button.

This is working file while I have data in the followers table but If I don't nothing shows (as there are no rows) - How could I implement this in my PHP? So also if there are no rows in 'followers table' echo follow button?

Comment: Before the `if($tables['followerid']!=$table['id'])` statement, echo the two value and see what you get.

Comment: I only get the username - no buttons are displayed

Comment: what are two extra braces?

Comment: sorry, I think I included them by mistake off the previous loop

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

you can try do it like that

```
$selecty = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");

$rowsy = mysql_num_rows($selecty);

echo '<td>'. $table["username"]. '</td>';
echo '<td>';

while ($tables = mysql_fetch_assoc($selecty)) {
    if($tables['followerid']!=$table['id'] and $tables['followerid'] != '') {
        echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="follow"></a>'; 
    } else if($tables['followerid'] =$table['id'] and $tables['followerid'] !='') {
        echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="following"></a>';
    } else {
        echo what you like here when $tables['followerid'] = ''
    }
}

echo '</td>';
echo "<tr>";
```

edit

```
      class="follow">'.'</a>'
                      ^------------you dont have to make point and single quotes here

   $selecty = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM followers WHERE    userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");

 $rowsy = mysql_num_rows($selecty);
 echo '<table><tr>';
  echo '<td>'. $table["username"]. '</td></tr>';

 if ($tables['followerid'] !== ''){
 while ($tables = mysql_fetch_assoc($selecty)) {
 echo '<tr><td>';
if($tables['followerid']!=$table['id'] and $tables['followerid'] != '') {
    echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="follow"></a></td></tr>'; 
} else if($tables['followerid'] =$table['id'] and $tables['followerid'] !='') {
    echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="following"></a></td></tr>';
} else {
    echo "what you like here  </td></tr>";
}
}
}
else {

 echo "do your code here " ; 
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: buttons ? what buttons do u mean ? u have links `<a>` u can do them in `else`

Comment: sorry - it still isn't showing the links - it shows the <td>username<td> but not the following <td>

Comment: what this variable `$table`?

Comment: $table is from the previous while loop getting the 'id' from mysql of users

Comment: replace this and  see if the link appears or not `<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="follow">gggggggg</a>` replace it in the first link and in second link

Comment: if I put data into my mysql table it works fine, it's only when there is nothing in there

Comment: I don't get why there are a load of else statements with 'do your code here' ?

Comment: this is when there is no data in your sql u put code it there what u want to show

Answer (score 0):

Put a boolean (FALSE) at the start of the 'followers' loop such that if it gets crossed make it TRUE. If you get outside the loop and it's still FALSE then add the button anyway.

```
$trip = FALSE;

while ($tables = mysql_fetch_assoc($selecty)) {
  if($tables['followerid']!=$table['id']) {
    echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="follow">'.'</a>'; 
  } else {
    $trip = TRUE;
    echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$table['id'].'" class="following">'.'</a>';
  }
}

if( !$trip ) echo '<a href="#" data-userid="'.$_SESSION['id'].'" class="follow">'.'</a
```

Comment: this kinda works...but if a user is not following somebody it repeats it twice - so class="follow"

Comment: or if a user follows all of the users it shows both the follow class and following class

Comment: Add the $trip to the if{} clause also.

Comment: Add a 2nd type of $trip - or a counter.

Comment: is it something to do with nesting the while loop why it isnt working?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21644/discussion-between-ethrbunny-and-andrew-charlton)

Comment: sorry I went off, would you like to continue?